# Need help ID’ing cloth wires

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am replacing an old chandelier with an LED light fixture and found that it was connected to old cloth wires. See link below to a photo I took. I can’t identify which one is the hot and which one is neutral even after using a voltage tester pen.  I found that there were four wires all twisted together (on left) and one by itself (on right). The light fixture I got has a hot, neutral and ground. Any suggestions? TIA

(https://pasteboard.co/tsOpjApOVdAC.jpg)

Comment: With the breaker **off**, check continuity between the wires and the box. One wire should be neutral heading back towards the breaker panel - that wire should show continuity (because of neutral/ground bond in the panel) with the box and most if not all of the others should not. A little odd to have 4 wires together though in a box that looks like it only has 2 cables coming in, but not really clear.

Comment: Do you know where the old fixture was connected? The new one should work fine even if you mix up hot and neutral.

Comment: The single wire should be your switched hot from the switch.  That goes to the black of the light.  Place the proper size of a wire nut on the four.  The white from the light should go to the wires under the wire nut.

Answer (score 1):

Check for continuity or voltage between the wires and ground (the box).  The wire with continuity and no voltage is neutral; the wire with no continuity and 120V is hot.